# How to make an image blink in a random position?

Tags: java, image, applet, graphics2d, japplet

I have an image inside the `JApplet` and I want it to appear in a random position.  It will disappear after 1 second and appear again, in another random position.

How do I implement 'blinking in a random position'?

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Random extends JApplet
{

 Image ball;

  public void init()
  {
    try
    {
        URL pic = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "ball.gif");
        ball = ImageIO.read(pic);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
       if (ball != null)
      {
        g.drawImage(ball,50,50,50,50,this);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Image Blinker]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

class ImageBlinker extends JComponent {

    BufferedImage image;
    boolean showImage;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    Random r;

    ImageBlinker() {
        // put your image reading code here..
        image = new BufferedImage(32,32,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(0,0,32,32);
        // END - image read

        r = new Random();
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (image!=null) {
                    if (!showImage) {
                        int w = image.getWidth();
                        int h = image.getHeight();
                        int rx = getWidth()-w;
                        int ry = getHeight()-h;
                        if (rx>-1 && ry>-1) {
                            x = r.nextInt(rx);
                            y = r.nextInt(ry);
                        }
                    }
                    showImage = !showImage;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(600,listener);
        timer.start();

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this);
        timer.stop();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        if (showImage && image!=null) {
            g.drawImage(image,x,y,this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ImageBlinker();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: nice blinks, i really appreciate. what if I put an "image.gif" inside the oval? Is it possible?

Comment: *what if I put an "image.gif" inside the oval?*  <head-desk/> What happened when you **tried it**? *Is it possible?*  It is easy for me or any other number of people, but I cannot say if is possible for you.

Answer (score 2):

For my money, I'd put the Image in an ImageIcon, the ImageIcon in a JLabel, and then use a Swing Timer and a Random object to randomly move the JLabel about. You'd have to move it in a container (the contentPane will do) whose layout has been set to null, and you'll have to specify the size of the JLabel as its preferredSize for this to work.

Comment: but the image doesn't appear when I use the ImageIcon, It only appear when set it to Image. I use the URL to make it appear but without JLabel.

Comment: Then please show us what you're doing because it works fine for me.

Comment: I have edited my question and added my code above. The code their is just to appear the image inside the JApplet.

Comment: You should never draw directly in a JApplet using paint. Instead you should either draw in a JComponent such as a JPanel and add it to the applet or make it the applet's contentPane or use an ImageIcon in a JLabel as I suggest. Can you show us how you tried to use my recommendation, the bit you said doesn't work for you?

Comment: I just replace the try and catch with this code :Container container=getContentPane();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("ball.gif");
        JLabel label=new JLabel(icon);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        container.add(label); --> still its inside the init() method but doesn't appear anything.

Comment: @Mikel: you must post all code as an edit to your original question. We can't read unformatted code in comments. Also, get your image using the ImageIO.read method, the one that takes an InputStream as a parameter, and then get your InputStream using the Class#getResourceAsStream(...) method.

Comment: Or else just use the Image you obtain above in your current code and add that to an ImageIcon and that to a JLabel. Again you need to set the layout of the contentPane to null, you need to specify the size of your JLabel and its position for it to show, and you need to add it to the contentPane.